# Print Armstrong numbers between 1 to 1000000

Tags: r

```
armstrong <- function(x) {
  tmp <- strsplit(as.character(x), split="")  
  cubic <- sapply(tmp, function(y)sum(as.numeric(y)^3))
  return(cubic == x)
}

s <- 1:1000000
s[armstrong(s)]
```

How can I print Armstrong numbers between 1 to 1000000? I wrote this code, but it only prints `1 153 370 371 407` numbers. I want to print 1 to 1 million Armstrong numbers.

Comment: In my opinion you should not use the exponent "3" all the time. for digits of length 4, the exponent should be 4 in an armstong number, or? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
s <- 99:1000000

armstrong <- vapply(s, function(x) {

    tmp <- strsplit(as.character(x), split="")

    exponent <- length(tmp[[1]])

    sum <- sapply(tmp, function(y)sum(as.numeric(y)^exponent))

return(sum == x)
},FUN.VALUE = 1)

s[armstrong == 1]

# [1]    153    370    371    407   1634   8208   9474  54748  92727  93084
#[11] 548834
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s <- 1:1000000
s[sapply(s, function(x) 
 sum(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split="")))^nchar(as.character(x))) == x)]
 #[1]      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9    153    370    371    407   1634   8208   9474  54748  92727  93084 548834
```